# How to implement OnItemLongClickListener for items in a ListFragment

Tags: android, android-listview, android-listfragment

I have created a ListFragment using a cursor adapter. I have implemented an OnItemClickListener and it works fine. How do i Implement an OnItemLongClickListener to perform another function with the list item?
My list fragment comes from the android support library to support a minimum api of 8.

Comment: What exactly does "doesn't work" means?

Comment: i use android studio, it underlines onitemlongclicklistener() in the getlistview() line and ask me to import an AdapterViewICS file and implements the onitemlongClick with the first parameter being AdapterViewICS<?> arg0, but it is also underlined red, makin the whole project unbuildable.

Comment: Use `new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener...` and import the `AdapterView` class from the sdk(not the compatibility package).

Comment: @Luksprog it doesnt work

Comment: All you need to do is `getListView().setOnLongItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener(){...})` and import the proper `AdapterView` class from the android sdk.